# How to add row views to a linear layout dynamically while keeping them unique

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, unique, dynamically-generated

I do not know if this is the best way to do it, but I have a LinearLayout container like so:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnlPrefixItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="@color/panel_border">

        ... items here ...

    </LinearLayout>
```

This will contain child items, but I do not know how many until runtime. Each child item has three TextViews :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArabic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@color/list_item_arabic_background"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_arabic_foreground"
        android:minWidth="25dp"
        android:text="@string/panel_arabic_sample"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMeaning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@color/panel_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="7dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:text="@string/panel_meaning_sample"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTechnical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:background="@color/panel_content"
            android:textColor="@color/match_pos_subtitle"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:text="@string/panel_technical_sample"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At runtime, when I have the data I inflate the child row layout and dynamically add to the parent container, all seems fine, however all the rows end up being identical, set to the values of the last row :

```
private void clearContainerPanels()
{
    __pnlPrefixItems.removeAllViews();
    ...
}

private void populateDetails(Match match)
{
    clearContainerPanels(); // clear all child rows first

    // add new child rows
    for (Pos _p : match.Prefix.Items)
    {
        LinearLayout _itemRow = (LinearLayout) __inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_row, __pnlPrefixItems);
        TextView _txtArabic = (TextView) _itemRow.findViewById(R.id.txtArabic);
        TextView _txtMeaning = (TextView) _itemRow.findViewById(R.id.txtMeaning);
        TextView _txtTechnical = (TextView) _itemRow.findViewById(R.id.txtTechnical);
        _txtArabic.setText(_p.Vowelled);
        _txtMeaning.setText(_p.Meaning);
        _txtTechnical.setText(_p.Technical);
    }
```

}

If there are 3 rows, all three have the values of the 3rd one. How best to solve this? I understand I can use lists, however it seems overkill for this at the moment.

**End Result:**

[image]

Comment: Log.d _p.Vowelled, _p.Meaning and _p.Technical inside the for loop

Comment: Well, It seems you really need a custom `ListView`, not a LinearLayout.

Comment: ok,  but first meaning is "Meaning... " while second and third are "The", so not all rows are the same

Comment: @pskink yes it seemed to be getting the "Determinative" and "ال" from the defaults defined in the XML, it so happened that the last thing it added was also those, I have removed the defaults so now the screenshot is different.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes but you see most of the time there will be nothing or one item in the `LinearLayout`, there can be up to 3. Also I would like all the text to be selectable. Doesn't feel right to use a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has an error:

```
LinearLayout _itemRow = (LinearLayout) __inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_row, __pnlPrefixItems);
```

It should be changed to:

```
LinearLayout _itemRow = (LinearLayout) __inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_row, __pnlPrefixItems, false);
__pnlPrefixItems.addView(_itemRow);
```

Explanation: inflate() returns the view group, not the inflated view, unless the boolean third arg is added (and it must be false). As a result findViewById() will have the wrong scope.

Source: [LayoutInflater javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: "`attachToRoot` ... If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML." -- does not make sense to me but it works.

Comment: Hello. I want to apply click listener in the inflated layout.